# Flying for the first time tomorrow, is a physical boarding pass required or is the app enough?

Tags: uk, airport-security, sas

I am flying for the first time tomorrow, and one of my many many worries is regarding the boarding pass. I am flying with SAS and I have checked in on the SAS APP. It then shows me a boarding pass with a little QR code on it. 
My questions:
Is this enough to complete my journey, or do I need to print something off or go to a desk at the airport?
If I have checked in and have my boarding pass (via the app) do I just need to head straight to security once I arrive at the airport (I have no luggage)?

Apologies if this has been answered before. I'm so confused and worrying a little because I'll be running on a very tight schedule.

Thank you all

Comment: On many, many occasions, I have found it to incredibly useful that I have simply printed the boarding pass.  Computers and phones are crap, and there are frequently situations where for one reason or another the scanner/whatever is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The app is sufficient. You just go straight to security and scan your QR code there. If you're worried about running out of battery on your phone, you can print a boarding pass in one of the self check-in machines to have as a backup. Good luck on your first flight!

Comment: Thank you so much, it's such a relief to know what I'm doing now.

Answer (score 2):

The QR code should be enough.  However, make sure your device has sufficient battery charge left to last until after you board the plane (for that reason alone, I nearly always print a physical copy as well).

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I think I will print a copy off just in case.

Comment: I think this is overkill. unless you start the trip at 3% battery, or watch videos for three hours before boarding, it should be no problem

Comment: @Aganju I used to have a phone with unreliable battery figures, which can jump from 50% to 10%, and then switch off itself within a couple minutes (but not always). I dont't think Nick's solution is an overkill, but OP should use his own judgement, and having a paper boading pass should aleviate some sort of anxiety for first-time flight travellers.

Comment: Not overkill in my opinion. On a normal day, all is fine, then you get some annoying delay, and suddenly you're sat at the gate for an hour or two, you need to call people to tell them you're late, you get bored, do a bit of surfing ... The effort to print a copy is low, the day you need it you are *so* happy. It's not just at the gate it's the other security checks you may need to pass.